# All my posts don't show, only the headline is displayed on the homepage

Tags: posts, permalinks, errors

I'm new to WordPress. I host my site on GoDaddy. Last night, all my posts stopped showing when clicked. Works fine on homepage, but when clicked it would respond "Error 404"... Please Help me out! My Pages work fine... My site is [`www.shoutnaija.com`](http://www.shoutnaija.com)

Comment: You should probably talk to your host.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with your site hosted with Godaddy. The issue lies with the code within.

You are most likely using a plugin that pulls content from news services. The error is occurring right after the Twitter share link:

```
<i class="icon-tweet icon"></i>
    <span>
    The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

Your page stops rendering after the error occurs, meaning the plugin is not handling errors properly.

It's also worth noting your site is using a content caching plugin W3TC:

```
<!-- Performance optimized by W3 Total Cache. Learn more: http://www.w3-edge.com/wordpress-plugins/
```

You might want to disable it for the time being for troubleshooting purposes.